# What are common Windows service design patterns?

Tags: windows, design-patterns, windows-services

Where can I find good information on **common design patterns that might be employed when building a new Windows service?**

**Update: I'm asking if there are common designs that are used when constructing a service.*

*For example:  I have seen a single task get executed on a timer (this seems very common when constructing a service).   I've also seen 'queue workers' deployed as services.  Are there other common design patterns when designing software to be run as a service?*

Comment: I guess I'm confused by the questions.  To my knowledge there's really only one way of creating a service, that's the way that's documented in the Windows SDK.  There are a number of frameworks which attempt to automate the process, are you asking which framework you should use?

Comment: I have added clarification.  Please let me know if I'm still being unclear.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A Windows service is merely a background process that is not tied to an interactive desktop (although it can optionally communicate with one). The uses for such a concept are many and varied. Common uses for a service (not mutually exclusive):

- Listen for an incoming request from somewhere else (e.g. TCP, RPC, COM, HTTP) and act on it.
- Schedule a task to occur at a certain time, at regular intervals, or when some other condition becomes true, e.g. watching the file system.

The only pattern I can think of that you should apply to all your services is: Separate out the part that decides *when* to do the work from the part that *does* the work. This will make it easier to unit test and re-use the various parts.